Randomly perturbed function has no accumulated critical point almost surely?
Given a smooth function $f$ and a smooth manifold $\mathcal{M}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, define the set
$$
S(v):=\{x:{\rm Proj}_{T_x{\mathcal{M}}}(v)=\nabla_{\mathcal{M}}f(x)\}.
$$
Is correct to say that $S(v)$ only has isolated points for almost all $v\in\mathbb{R}^d$?
Notes.

The Riemannian metric is induced by the scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ in Euclidean space.
I think Morse-Sard theorem and implicit function theorem can be helpful, but I cannot prove it.


OP, do you have any comments on the answer below? I find it pretty convincing.
